# Plotly Dash + DynamoDB? Backend Logic?

Tags: python, frontend, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm currently developing a Plotly Dash app and I would like to have data update every 10 minutes or so. I'm currently using `dcc.Interval` to accomplish this and data is fetched from AWS DynamoDB using boto3. How do I make one single entity accomplish this task? The problem I see is that multiple instances of my Dash apps will be fetching the same data at different times if the app is started at different times. I would like a single backend process to fetch this data and for each app instance to just read it. Fetching the data takes about 15-20 seconds total.

Here's the currently callback function.
After `FetchData(Sessions2).scan_save_all_records()` and `CleanData.clean_save_raw_data` are both called, a couple dataframes are saved via `df.to_csv`.

```
@app.callback(
    Output("last_updated_timer", "children"),
    Input("interval_component", "n_intervals"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_data(n):

    print("Fetching data...")
    FetchData("Sessions2").scan_save_all_records()

    print("Cleaning data...")
    CleanData.clean_save_raw_data()

    print("Done!")
    return f"Data last updated {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}."
```

Additionally, how can I return intermediate loading messages (like this ones in my print statements)?

I'm new to web development. I'm a little confused on how to approach this problem.

Comment: I would recommend to start reading this https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks

Comment: Ok. I'm still confused on how to use flask-caching to store a dataframe. Do I create a function that queries and returns the dataframe, then decorate this function in `@cache.memoize()`?

Comment: Basically, yes. You just have to set up and configure the cache. In case you want to use a Redis cache, you will of course need to launch a Redis server first, e.g. using Docker. Then provide the Redis URL to the cache configuration. In the given example this is done via an environment variable.

Comment: Gotcha. How do I prevent multiple instances firing this callback at different times using `dcc.Interval`? If different users start my app at different times, they will be on different `dcc.Interval` timers, and this expensive query is run many times. How can I get this to run once every couple minutes for everybody?

Comment: You just need to bin the time intervals, e.g. using floor/integer division on the corresponding unix timestamps and use this bin label as input to your cached function.

Comment: That makes sense to me, but won't each instance still run this query, only at the same time? For example, if 5 people have my app open, they'll each run a data refresh every _X_ minutes at the same time. How do I get a single operation independent of the amount of users? What am I missing?

Comment: This is handled by the `dcc.Store` component. I recommend to read again carefully the section *Example 3 - Caching and Signaling* in https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks. And also have a look at the code by clicking on *Here's what this example looks like in code:*

Comment: @CarlosHorn Ok, I think I am understanding; in Example 3, how do I instead have `print(f'Computing value with {value}')` modify a callback instead of printing to console? The main issue I have is that I cannot decorate the cached function, because it is also returning something that is not a callback output. I would like a "Data last updated...(time)" to go into an HTML component but it seems I cannot do this without decorating the cached function. Any tips?